# Swapping image file and adding css class to a img tag on scroll with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, setattribute

I would like to swap an image file on a 10px scroll, and along with the image swap I would also like to swap a css class. I was able to get a script working for swapping the image file, but adding a class to the img tag is not working. Is there a reason setAttribute is not working?

JS:

```
<script>
      window.onscroll = function() {
        growShrinkLogo()
      };

      function growShrinkLogo() {
        var Logo = document.getElementById("Logo")
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
          $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','images/logo-sm.png').setAttribute('class', 'smlogo');
        } else {
          $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','images/logo.png').setAttribute('class', 'lgclass');
        }
      }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setAttribute` is a native method on an element and not a jQuery. Use [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) for that purpose when working with jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

`.setAttribute()` is a JavaScript method and in these lines you're using a jQuery structure to switch `src` attribute value, so why don't use jQuery `toggleClass()`?

**Your code adapted:**

```
<script>
  window.onscroll = function() {
    growShrinkLogo()
  };

  function growShrinkLogo() {
    var Logo = document.getElementById("Logo")
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
      $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','images/logo-sm.png').toggleClass('smlogo').toggleClass('lgclass');
    } else {
      $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','images/logo.png').toggleClass('lgclass').toggleClass('smlogo');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know that `setAttribute` won't work for you as its specific to DOM elements.

You can set both of your attributes i.e. **src** and **class** through **'attr'** function only without using any additional functions like `addClass` or `toggleClass` as the **'attr'** function accept multiple values.

You can refer the following code snippet-

`$('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr({'src':'images/logo-sm.png','class':'smlogo'});`